# Rejecting edits because they "Failed to correct critical issues with the post"

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits

So I just made it past 2k rep, and I've been reviewing some edits.

Once, one of **my** suggested edits was rejected because it apparently

> Failed to correct critical issues with the post

I found a suggested edit that deserved that marking, but I was unable to find that reason in the list.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, custom reasons.

Comment: @MarkKirby - OK.... but the only box that allows for custom reasons is "This edit causes harm"

Comment: They changed the reasons recently, the thinking being if it fails to correct critical issues the reviewer will fix them with the "accept and edit" or "reject and edit" buttons.

Comment: @Seth - Would you please add that as an answer, also mentioning MarkKirby's comment?

Comment: @AndroidDev For me the box says "Describe how this edit would make the post worse" but you can just put anything you like in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They changed the reject reasons recently, the thinking being if it fails to correct critical issues the reviewer will fix them with the "accept and edit" or "reject and edit" buttons.

More on that over here: [What guidance should be given when edits are rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/)